# Good translation (manually) software

Tags: translation

I'm looking for a good translation software. i do not mean something that does all the translation automatically for me.

But rather something that aids me in translating large pieces of text, since it has to be a perfect translation i can't leave it to computers alone.

Something like http://translate.google.com/toolkit but with more options/functions would be great. Preferably freeware ofcourse (But paid is not a problem). At the moment i use the Google toolkit since it's adequate for now, but i really need something more advanced.

But looking for such software on google etc. is really hard because of the confusion with translation services and things like babelfish.

Do you know any software like this? and maybe want to share your thoughts/experiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need a tool with [translation memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory).  Professional translators use computer-aided translation (CAT) tools such as [Wordfast](http://www.wordfast.net/), [SDL Trados](http://www.trados.com/en/), [Lingo Tek](http://www.lingotek.com/EN/index.php), and [Systran](http://systransoft.com) (thanks to Joe Internet for the last one).

Comment: Also Systran: http://www.systransoft.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: @S.Hoekstra what was the solution you chose, from the ones mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Last year I had occasion to look into internationalization and localization software, and some of them had features that looked like automatic translation.  The software I was looking at cost something vaguely like a couple thousand a seat, to give you an idea, but I wasn't looking for anything like machine translation.  (For my project, we'd just translate everything with locally available translators.)

So, google for software internationalization and follow links.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at Transit NXT (www.star-transit.com), STAR's integrated computer assisted translation environment. It comes with conversion filters for all the main  formats used today in content creation, features its proprietary high-productivity translation editor. It also has and integrated terminology management component as well as project management and quality assurance functionality.

Comment: Hi Michael. If you're affiliated with a product, please disclose that. Otherwise your posts will be removed as spam/promotional.

Answer (score -2):

I've tried a few, and my favorite is currently Kilgray's MemoQ (http://www.memoq.com). They have a free version that has some annoyances, but is ultimately more helpful than unhelpful. (The paid version is quite expensive.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.