# What computer-assisted translation (CAT) system could you recommend?

Tags: translation, localization

Ok, if you're in enterprise software development, you've probably faced with the problem of localization. When it comes to translating the texts of a certain piece of software to a certain language, you have to:

- generate a list of phrases used in your application (assembly resources, database resources, various static files, etc.)
- find out a native speaker to take over the translation itself
- pass the texts to this person is a good understandable format and make sure it is clear for that guy not to translation tags, reserved words, whatever "untranslatable"
- get the translations back to the application and make sure build script picks this up
- in future, reuse these translations for other applications, other versions of the same application, etc.

All this is not trivial and there's a type of software to take over this, called computer-assisted translation software.

I wonder if any of you have dealt with any of this kind of systems and can recommend any? Below are the main features I find vital for my case:

- it should be a web application which I can setup inside my company's domain
- a translator should be able to work online or download the snapshot of product texts in a certain language and work offline, then upload the results of the work
- it should have integration with build script, for instance, if my build process produces a translation file with new texts, it should have watchers to pick such files, upload new keys, auto-complete with existing translations, etc.
- it should have a translation memory feature: auto-complete of existing translations, possible, an option to first machine-translate the text
- it is very desired to be a .NET system and to be extensible with plugins

I know there's [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_assisted_translation), but it would be nice to hear real feedback from the fields :)
Thank you!

P.S. And I don't think it is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/119289/good-translation-manually-software).

Comment: "Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."

Answer (score 0):

I work for a [translation company](http://www.tomedes.com) . Most of the translators who use CAT tools choose SDL TRADOS, although it is rather expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, JIm. Besides its price, does it have a steep learning curve? The translators we work with are not professional translators and we don't require any special skills, just being a native speaker.